# Iframe Same-Origin Policy Go back in an iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, browser, same-origin-policy

I have this iFrame on my Clients site and it shows a page from a different origin. So the same-Origin policy kicks in.

What I want to do is have a button in the Viewport to go Back in the iFrame but Apparently It's not allowed by the browser.

I am using this code:

```
document.getElementById("mainSearch").contentWindow.history.go(-1);
```

But It gives an error as expected.

Ideal solution will be to somehow implement this Back Button and I don't have control over the cross-origin page.

Thank you

Comment: Can't do it from regular page Javascript.  If the iframe page cooperates, you can send a message to it and the iframe itself can process that message and do the back command.  But, you can't tell it to go back from another origin if the iframe page isn't cooperating.

Comment: You just want to change the `iframeElement.src`? You know if you don't have CORS access then you can't use JavaScript on the `iframeElement.contentWindow`, right? Of course, you can put your own button above the `iframeElement` and just do like `iframeElement.src = 'newPage.php'` or whatever.